# Retrieving image uri from an item in grid

Tags: android, gridview, uri, android-imageview, aviary

I am trying to read these uris from each selected item in my gridview, then store them in a Uri array and read them from there.

Here is the code I have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < imagegrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
                Uri uri = (Uri) imageAdapter.getItem(i);
                View view = imagegrid.getChildAt(i);
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                // ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

                if (checkBox.isChecked())
                {
                    editImagesUri[count] = uri;
                }
            }
```

Before I run, I have no errors, but when I do I get "Integer cannot be cast to Uri." Is there any sort of substitute for this method I am using? I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Your getItem function is not returning URIs, its returning an int.  Either change it to return URI, or have an int->URI map somewhere.